# ActionScript 3 Vector sort suddenly extremely slow?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sorting

While playing around with as' vector.sort() I found out that it behaves normally in every case except where it needs to sort a vector with only 2 or 3 distinctive values. If this is the case, the sort() function runs extremely slowly.
Here's my code:

```
var test:Vector.<int>=new Vector.<int>  ;
for (var i:int=0; i<6000; i++) {
    test.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
}
var timer:Number
var timer2:Number
timer=new Date().getTime();
test.sort(compare)
timer2=new Date().getTime();
trace(timer2-timer)
function compare(x:int,y:int):Number {
    if (x>y) {
        return 1;
    } else if (x<y) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

simply copypaste this code.
What might be the problem here?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't actually happen with 2 or 3 values, more precisely, the effect is more noticeable the fewer distinct values there are in the vector. Each sorting algorithm has it's cons and pros. The built-in one (I reckon it's the bubble sort) will perform nearly it's worst case when there are few distinct values. You could try this simple alternative (sort of radix sort), but notice that it will have larger memory footprint, and the larger the more distinct values there are in the vector.

```
package examples 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

/**
 * An example for stackoverflow.com
 * @author wvxvw
 */
public class KindOfRadixSort extends Sprite
{

    public function KindOfRadixSort() 
    {
        super();
        this.test();
    }

    private function test():void
    {
        var test:Vector.<int> = new <int>[];
        var timer:Number;
        var timer2:Number;

        for (var i:int; i < 6000; i++) test.push(Math.random() * 5);

        timer = new Date().getTime();
        test.sort(compare);
        timer2 = new Date().getTime();
        trace(timer2 - timer); // 2488

        timer = new Date().getTime();
        this.kindOfRadixSort(test);
        timer2 = new Date().getTime();
        trace(timer2 - timer); // 3
    }

    private function compare(x:int, y:int):int
    {
        var result:int;
        if (x > y) result = 1;
        else if (x < y) result = -1;
        return result;
    }

    private function kindOfRadixSort(vector:Vector.<int>):Vector.<int>
    {
        // Arrays are sparse, therefore we don't allocate memory when having
        // gaps between filled indices as we would have we used vector.
        var cache:Array = [];
        var result:Vector.<int> = new <int>[];
        var i:int;

        for each (i in vector)
        {
            if (cache[i]) (cache[i] as Vector.<int>).push(i);
            else cache[i] = new <int>[i];
        }
        // A for-each loop could be better here, and, in fact, for-each on
        // arrays usually provides elements in order 0..length, however,
        // the specs say the order is undefined.
        for (i = cache.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (cache[i] is Vector.<int>)
                result = (cache[i] as Vector.<int>).concat(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue: Vector.sort() of 50,000 value objects on a field with three distinct values: ~2 minutes.  I then call almost exactly the exact same sort, the only difference being that I break the tie (when x==y) on a secondary field with a unique value (that is to say, on a field with 50,000 distinct values): less than 1 sec!  Here's the sort function code to illustrate what I mean:

```
private function vastlyImprovedVectorSortFunc(x:MyVO, y:MyVO):Number
{
    if(x.fieldWithThreeValues > y.fieldWithThreeValues)
        return 1;
    else
        if(x.fieldWithThreeValues < y.fieldWithThreeValues )
            return -1;
        else
            if(x.uniqueFieldWithManyValues > y.uniqueFieldWithManyValues)
                return 1;
            else
                if(x.uniqueFieldWithManyValues < y.uniqueFieldWithManyValues )
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
}
```

Bizarro world, right?!  It looks like I'm asking the function to do a lot more work, applying a secondary sort on a very unique field - but apparently the Vector's sort function performance degrades with a smaller number of distinct sort "bins" to put things into.  I discovered this when I was sorting my Vector on a fieldWithAboutTwentyValues, and the performance was still bad (~20 sec), but much improved.  It was then even better on a fieldWithAboutAHundredValues; so I thought, why not go whole-hog and just do a final sort on the (unique) primary key.

A game-changer for me!  Hope it helps someone else.  Surprised this isn't in the docs somewhere.